# Display data of API Google Maps

Tags: flutter, maps

I am currently developing an application with Flutter where I use the Google Maps API but I am having a problem with the display of data.

Indeed in my application it displays the arrival time (arrival_time) like this: 7:19pm.

But I would like it to display in this form: 19:19

Same for the travel time (duration) it displays 1hour24mins but I would like it to display 1h24.

How do I deal with these problems?

Thanks a lot for your help

Cordially
Thibault

Here is a screenshot:

[image: App Interface]

Answer (score 0):

If you can transform this dates to DateTime, then you could use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to transform the time.

For instance:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.now();
print(DateFormat.Hm().format(t));
```

This prints the time in 24 hours format.

You would also probably be able to also transform it to XhYm too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help.
So there you have it, I tried your solutions but it doesn't work.
What is strange is that when I call the API with a browser (Chrome) it displays the correct time (16:48).
But when I try in the app it returns 4:48 pm.
And suddenly I don't know how to solve this problem.
So if there are any additional parameters to pass, I would like to have them.
Thank you for your time
Cordially
Thibault